# Two identical datetimes not comparing equal

Tags: powershell, datetime, date-comparison

I have two dates that are identical as far as I can tell.

```powershell
$theDate = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00)
$otherDate = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00)
```

Executed in that order

Both of these show up as `Monday, May 11, 2015 12:00:00 AM`, but when I do `($theDate -eq $otherDate)` it returns false. I've tried `$theDate.equals($otherDate)` and  `(($theDate) -eq ($otherDate))` same thing.
The only thing I can get to return true is `($theDate -gt $otherDate)` 
Am I crazy or just a noob?

Comment: One thing you can do is `$theDate = (Get-Date).Date`. That uses [this property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a DateTime with only the date portion and a 0'd out time portion.

Comment: Just a hint - if you ever want to see the "exact" value of a `DateTime`, try checking out its `Ticks` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are forgetting about the millisecond field, which will be different for the two datetimes:

```powershell
PS > $theDate = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00)
PS > $otherDate = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00)
PS > $theDate.Millisecond
122  
PS > $otherDate.Millisecond
280
```

Setting these fields to the same value fixes the problem:

```powershell
PS > $theDate = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00 -Millisecond 000)
PS > $otherDate = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00 -Millisecond 000)
PS > $theDate -eq $otherDate
True
```

Although it might be easier to just assign the two variables to the same datetime:

```powershell
PS > $theDate = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00) 
PS > $otherDate = $theDate
PS > $theDate -eq $otherDate
True
```

Comment: What's interesting is that while `DateTime` is precise to the `Tick` (100ns), setting `-Millisecond 00` also zeros out the sub-millisecond portion too.

Comment: Alternatively, user `Get-Date` on a formatted `Get-Date` like `Get-Date (Get-Date -f "MM/dd/yyyy")` which will get you exactly midnight of the current day. Same for casting that as a `[datetime]` object such as `[datetime](get-date -f 'MM/dd/yyyy')`. So many options!

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `(Get-Date).Date.TimeOfDay` would be another option.